# Drupal 7 - How to create custom admin menu for client management of content

Tags: drupal-7, admin, customization

I'm trying to find the best way to create a user friendly admin menu for my client on the site I am building. So far I have been able to set access rights to the various types of content which I would like the client to edit, however this has some drawbacks in that I can't set provide access to individual blocks and the content overview page is wayy too confusing for the client.

Instead I would like to provide a structure like the following:

Admin Menu

- Services

  - Manage
  - Edit page header block
- Developments

  - Manage
  - Edit page header block
- Private commissions

  - Manage
  - Edit page header block

Each Manage option would take the client to a page like the Content overview page in the standard admin but it would automatically filter the results to include only the relevant content type e.g. the Manage option for developments page would show the user a list of the current developments and an option to Add a new one.

The Edit page header block options would take the user to the edit page for the relevant page header block.

Is this possible and if so how?

Any advice would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the Quickbar module?

Your description might be a little hard to understand what you're trying to accomplish, but if I get it right, you're trying to do a very custom "view" of the content pages. If you have to code it, then it's gonna take a long time.